# What is the double dash in this bash script excerpt doing

Tags: bash

I'm looking at an excerpt of bash and I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening here, particularly in the `COMPREPLY` assignment:

```
 case "$cur" in
    -*)
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-a -d -f -l -t -h --aoption --debug \
                               --file --log --test --help --' -- $cur ) );;
#   Generate the completion matches and load them into $COMPREPLY array.
#   xx) May add more cases here.
#   yy)
#   zz)
  esac
```

I understand we're assigning a value to `COMPREPLY` here based on the output of `compgen`, but what exactly is `--` doing in this assignment? Also, why the double semi-colon?

Comment: Really depends on COMPGEN now, doesn't it?

Comment: In git a double dash by itself separates program arguments and file names. You should probably read the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`compgen` is a `bash` builtin command, and the man pages say:

> Unless  otherwise  noted,  each  builtin command documented in this section as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the end of the options.

Since `$cur` is a variable that contains options (starting with `-`), the `--` is required (as mentioned in the man pages) to make a distinction between `compgen` options and input to be processed.

The following command is turning the option `--d` in `--debug`:

```
compgen -W '-a -d -f -l -t -h --aoption --debug --file --log --test --help --' -- --d
--debug
```

If you remove the separator `--`, the command throws an error, because `compgen` doesn't have any option starting with `--d`:

```
compgen -W '-a -d -f -l -t -h --aoption --debug --file --log --test --help --' --d
-bash: compgen: --: invalid option
compgen: usage: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option]  [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [word]
```

---

The `;;` is a separator used in the `case`, `esac` statement to terminate in your example the section started with `-*)`. Look at `bash` man pages for `Compound Commands` to get more info.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `--` really depends on the program you are executing. In this example `compgen`. Check the documentation of this program, it should be explained there.

A common convention that is not necessarily always followed is to treat everything after `--` as arguments, and do not try to parse as options or flags. As a concrete example, consider the case of running the GNU `ls` command to get a detailed listing of a file named `-t`. Running `ls -l -t` will treat `-t` as an option (order output by time), not as a filename argument. The solution is `ls -l -- -t`, this way `ls` will not try to parse the arguments after `--`. This is just a convention and not all programs may follow it. Note also that I wrote GNU `ls` not just `ls`, because other implementations may behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

The double dashes end the argument portion in getopt_long. From the manual.

> The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless
>   of the scanning mode.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long

The double semi colons end a case branch.